# Why?? @color/... isn't working with <font>

Tags: java, android, xml

I don't know why this is happening.

```
<string name="welcome_title"><font color="#00FFFF">Welcome</font></string>
```

Is working well, while

```
<string name="welcome_title"><font color="@color/light_blue">Welcome</font></string>
```

Is not working !!!

Here is my color

```
 <color name="light_blue">#00FFFF</color>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What does this have to do with Java?  I assume that what you show is XML since you added that tag.  What is it that is interpreting the XML?  Your XML seems well formed.  That's really all that can be said about XML on its own.  XML can't by itself be "not working" so long as it is valid XML syntax.  So what is it that is "not working"?  In what context is this XML being evaluated?  We need more information here to be able to help you.

Comment: Setting a color & font for a text in Android is done by adding the android:textColor  & android:fontFamily attributes to the TextView tag in your layout XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Issue:**

*You can not use @Resources inside formatted strings.*

- **Reason:**

*@Resources are theme/locale/state dependent. They are chosen according to the state. But a string doesn't needs a theme specific color. So it's not allowed.*

- **Solve:**

*Use color in the TextView where you wanna change the color, instead of string.*